# How to change the height of the android ListView Scrollbar thumb in android

Tags: android, listview

I set the drawable of ListView Scrollbar thumb in my listview through :

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/tabscroller
```

"tabscroller" is an image with small height. But thumb is appearing too large(default height of listview thumb) in my listview. Is there any way to change the height of thumb??

Comment: Normally, the size of the scrollbar is determined by the length of the thing being scrolled. I do not know if there is a way to change that behavior.